# linewidth is not working in google line chart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have used the google line chart, applied the line width as 5px but it is not working. I have used the following code,

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
 google.load('visualization', '1.0', {
   'packages': ['corechart']
 });


var options, data, chart;

$(function () {


// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

var tweets_table = $('#tweet-table');


function getData() {
    // Create array to hold our values for data table
    // Each key is an array which represents a "row" of data
    var values = [];

    // get our values
    $('#tweet-table tr').each(function (i, v) {

        // Create a new "row"
        values[i] = [];

        // Get either th or td and loop
        $(this).children('th,td').each(function (ii, vv) {
            if ($(this).is('td.tweet-count')) {
                // if we're looking at a numeric column be sure
                // to pass a integar to the Chart API
                values[i][ii] = parseFloat($(this).html());

            } else {
                // otherwise just get the text string
                values[i][ii] = $(this).html();
            }
        });
    });

    return values;
}

function drawChart() {
    var values = getData();

    // Create the data table.
    data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(values);

    // Set chart options
    options = {

        'width': '100%',
        'height': 500,
        fontSize: 16,
        fontName: 'Arial',

        tooltip: {isHtml: true},

        titlePosition: 'none',
        colors: ['#000'],
        areaOpacity: 0.1,
        pointSize: 15,
        pointShape: "circle",


      chartArea: { width: '90%' },
      lineWidth: 5,
      legend: {
            position: 'none'
        },

        hAxis: {
           textStyle: {
                fontSize:'16',
                color:'#555555',
                fontName: 'Arial'
                },


            format: '0.00', 
            minValue: -1 , 
        },
        vAxis: {
            textStyle: {
                fontSize:'16',
                color:'#555555',
                fontName: 'Arial'
                },
            titleTextStyle: {color: "#000",bold: "true",italic: "false"},
            title: "Total sales",
            gridlines: {
                color: '#ddd',
                 count: 6
            },
                baselineColor: '#522fa1',
        },


    };

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true});
    formatter.format(data, 0); // Apply formatter to first column

    var formatter2 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ fractionDigits: 5});
    formatter2.format(data, 1);

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}


// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
});


$(window).smartresize(function () {
   chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

And this is the html code,

```
<html class="no-js">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<meta charset="utf-8">  

<title>Charted Tweets</title>

<meta name="description" content="My Twitter RT&#39;s plotted on Google charts for netmag">
<!-- Google will often use this as its description of your page/site. Make it good. -->

<meta name="author" content="David Smith">



<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/typo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/site.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>



<body class="">

<div class="page">

    <h1>Tweets by <a href="http://www.twitter.com/get_dave" target="_blank">@get_dave</a> by date</h1>

    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div" style="position: relative; ">
    </div>

    <table class="table table-striped" id="tweet-table">
        <caption>@get_dave's Tweets by date</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Tweets</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>


            <tr>                    
                <td class="tweet-date">03/03/12</td>
                <td class="tweet-count">2</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>                    
                <td class="tweet-date">04/03/12</td>
                <td class="tweet-count">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>                    
                <td class="tweet-date">05/03/12</td>
                <td class="tweet-count">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>                    
                <td class="tweet-date">06/03/12</td>
                <td class="tweet-count">8</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>                    
                <td class="tweet-date">07/03/12</td>
                <td class="tweet-count">4</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>                    
                <td class="tweet-date">07/03/12</td>
                <td class="tweet-count">0</td>
            </tr><tr>                   
                <td class="tweet-date">07/03/12</td>
                <td class="tweet-count">0</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>                    
                <td class="tweet-date">08/03/12</td>
                <td class="tweet-count">3</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="_/js/debounce.js"></script>

<script src="_/js/functions.js"></script>


</body></html>
```

and my output is 
[image: here]

In output, the line width on the baseline is lighter than other linewidth. I need to equalize the line width at all places..

Comment: Are you talking about the width of the line graph itself or the width and color of the x axis?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. i am asking about the graph data lines(dark black lines) width. I have applied 5 px width for this. But this is not even at all places. The 2nd line from last have lighter width is placed on the graph  baseline when you see the output. But the other graph data lines are bold.. I want to make it also bold.. this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the horizontal axis is interfering with your line.  This is due to the minimum value of the vertical axis.

I played around with a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JohnPasquet/vdq4g5ad/)to replicate the issue.  Notice the minValue: -1 on the vAxis parameter.  It looks like you put that on the hAxis.

```
var options = {
    lineWidth: 5,
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'          
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity',
      minValue: -1
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you.. It is working very nice... thanks a lot..!